# Problems with mutiple array in foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is my first question here so i dont exactly know the normal style.

I have a problem with multiple arrays. My arrays are sorted this way:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 2
    [gebruikerData] => Array
        (
            [gebruiker1] => Array
                (
                    [merken] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => merk1
                            [1] => merk10
                            [2] => merk19
                        )

                    [loginnaam] => testfasdfasd
                    [geslacht] => Man
                    [persoonlijkheidsType] => TEST
                    [beschrijving] => fasdfasdfasd
                    [gebruikerID] => 19
                    [leeftijd] => 21
                )

            [gebruiker2] => Array
                (
                    [merken] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => merk1
                            [1] => merk9
                            [2] => merk36
                        )

                    [loginnaam] => test1233
                    [geslacht] => Man
                    [persoonlijkheidsType] => TEST
                    [beschrijving] => safasfd
                    [gebruikerID] => 20
                    [leeftijd] => 21
                )

        )

)
```

I need to retrieve all the information in this array. There can be as many fields gebruiker(number) as the database output, so i tried to use multiple foreach loops in eachother. My problem is that it is not possible to use the key from one foreach loop as index in another foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($gebruikerData as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($key as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        echo $key2;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have another idea how i could retrieve the information from the array? Or is if could use my own way with a slight change?

Comment: can you please tell me in which format you need the data

Comment: i need to echo the data inside the gebruiker-array. So merken, loginnaam etc. So the format i think is strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
foreach ($gebruikerData as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($key))
    {
        foreach ($key as $key2 => $value2)
        {
           if(is_array($key2))
           {
               foreach($key2 as $key3=>$value3)
                   echo $key3.'-'.$value3;
           }
           else
               echo $key2.'-'.$value2;
        }
     }
     else
         echo $key.'-'.$value;
}
```

Check for the $key is "array or not" each time,if it is array then it will fo to for loop orelse it will echo it directly

Comment: This is a nice idea and i now see that i failed by using the key, i should have used the value since the value is the array and not the key. And i've tried it now with value in stead of key and that works! Thanks alot for the quick answer.